# Resharper automatically add semicolon

Tags: resharper

Hi is that possible to force resharper to add automatically a semicolon? for example int.Pa and i see int.Parse so i click enter and I have int.Parse(|) while i still need to add ; after.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ctrl+Shift+Enter will do the trick.

Comment: nicee, but is that possible to have this option under Enter click? and much more important here is that the using your solution the cursor is under the line of code while i wish to have after pressing the enter button this: int.Parse(|);

Comment: i got answer from support from resharper, that it can be done by first pressening enter which will chose a method and put me inside the brackets and then ctr shift enter to finish the line with semicolon